# Put vector inside of a vector

Tags: c++, object, vector

i've been trying to make a function that can store vectors inside a vector and im having problems. I have made it work for vectors of int, but now im trying to use objects to fill it up and im having problems.

this is my header file:

```
class Animal
{
public:
    Animal();
    ~Animal();

    Animal(int , int, std::string);

    void setLength(int);
    void setWeight(int);
    void setLocation(std::string);

    int getLength();
    int getWeight();
    std::string getLocation();
private:
    int length_;
    int weight_;
    std::string location_;
};
```

this is my cpp file:

```
Animal::Animal(int length, int weight, std::string location) : length_(length), weight_(weight), location_(location)
{} 

void Animal::setLength(int length){
    length_ = length;
}
void Animal::setWeight(int weight){
    weight_ = weight;
}
void Animal::setLocation(std::string location){
    location_ = location;
}

int Animal::getLength(){
    return length_;
}
int Animal::getWeight(){
    return weight_;
}
std::string Animal::getLocation(){
    return location_;
}

Animal::~Animal()
{
}
```

and here is my main:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    Animal test;

    int i = -1;
    int d = -1;
    std::vector<std::vector<Animal> >N;
    std::vector<Animal>M;
    std::vector<Animal>D;

    while (i++ != 5)
    {
        M.push_back(test);
        M[i].setLength(20);
        M[i].setLocation("test");
        M[i].setWeight(30);
    }

    N.push_back(M);

    while (d++ != 5)
    {
        D.push_back(test);
        D[i].setLength(111);
        D[i].setLocation("test2");
        D[i].setWeight(222);
    }

    N.push_back(D);

    std::cout << N[0][4].getLength() << std::endl;
    std::cout << N[1][4].getLength();

    return 0;
}
```

When i try to build i get two errors:

> error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall Animal::Animal(void)" (??0Animal@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function _wmain

And

> error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals

Can anyone of you see what I have done wrong? And maybe some of you have a better solution to my problem.

Comment: You don't have an implementation of the default constructor of `Animal`.

Comment: You forgot to define `Animal();`.  You need to since you declared it.

Comment: And it has nothing to do with vectors.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Made it work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The linker error will likely go away by placing curly braces next to your default constructor...

```
Animal() {}
```

In addition, I noticed a bug in your code. To fix it, change this...

```
while (d++ != 5)
{

    D.push_back(test);

    D[i].setLength(111);
    D[i].setLocation("test2");
    D[i].setWeight(222);
}
```

to this...

```
while (d++ != 5)
{

    D.push_back(test);

    D[d].setLength(111);
    D[d].setLocation("test2");
    D[d].setWeight(222);
}
```

and it will work fine.

Comment: When I compile mine, I get no linker errors, and get the right output which is 20 and 111.

Comment: But the question is about OP's code, not yours. OP's code has a linker error, and your suggestion doesn't address that.

Comment: My bad. I got the linker error too and fixed it but forgot about it when noticed the bug.